# how to Check like status from an array of userIds mongoDb node Js in a single db hit?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an feed collection like this.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5989986f93d2f911f44d58f0"),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-08T10:54:39.984Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-08-16T10:36:01.254Z"),
"subCategory" : "35",
"category" : "49",
"title" : "Toilet Ek Prem Katha Official Trailer | Akshay Kumar | Bhumi Pednekar | 11 Aug 2017",
"feedType" : "USER_VIDEO_OWN",
"userId" : "5989954993d2f911f44d58ef",
"rating" : [],
"share" : [],
"likes" : [ 
    "597835b7efb7eb000436f5a1", 
    "5989951d6b97e904a0331091", 
    "5989954993d2f911f44d58ef", 
    "598994f26b97e904a0331090"
],
"isDeleated" : 0,
"isActive" : 1,
"lastComment" : null,
"rateCount" : 0,
"recommended" : 0,
"playCount" : 0,
"commentCount" : 11,
"likeCount" : 4,
"url" : "",
"text" : "Movie !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!",
"video" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ym4EJQ7XORk",
"image" : "",
"__v" : 0}
```

Their is an like array which contain those user's userIds who like this feed.
I want to get an like flag at the time of get feed if my userId exist in this array the flag true or 1 else flag is false or 0.

Currently i am using an extra for loop to achieve this but i think its not an good way.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i].isLiked = 0;
            for (var j = 0; j < data[i].likes.length; j++) {
                var likedUserId = data[i].likes[j];
                if (likedUserId == b.userId) {
                    data[i].isLiked = 1;
                    data[i].followStatus = 1;
                    data[i].likes = '';
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you going for readability or performance?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do 2 steps of Logic

1.Fetch the data from DB using Query

2.Check for whether the user liked that feed.

Overview of code:

```
var _ = require('underscore');

Db.find({}, function(err,res){
     for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
         if(_.conatins(data[i].likes), b.userId) {
                res[i].isLiked = 1;
         } else {
                res[i].isLiked = 0;
         }
     }
})
```

Comment: This logic seems sounds good and working fine but i want to do all thing at the end of db level . I don't want to use for loop for this.

Comment: something like $lookup in mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var data = require('./models/feed.js');//This is the schema I assumed it as data
app.get('/likes/:userId',function(req,res){
data.find({'likes':req.params.userId},function(err,result){
if(result == true){
res.json(result);
}
else if(result == false){
res.json("id does not exists");
}
else(err) res.json('false');
});
});
```

Here in my code if you pass a userId through parameters you will get the response you want.Hope this helps for you.

Comment: The above peace of code will return which i liked only but i need all the feed     with like true or false flag.

Comment: check the code I edited the code as per your requirement

Comment: By using find() function with userid everything comes into result variable.You will get the feed in result variable.